# Custom font in a storyboard?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, storyboard, custom-font

I have a font added to my iOS project.  It's in the project and copied when the project builds.  It appears to be a valid font and will show up if I list all fonts on the device through the app.  I have the plist set up properly to include the font.  I can't seem to get the find to show up to use it in my text controls, buttons, etc in Xcode 4.2's storyboard section.  Further it doesn't appear to allow me to type the font name, it forces me to use the font dialog.  I attempted to install this font in the system as well, but cannot seem to get it to show in this list.  Do I need to do this in code only or can I do this through the storyboard interface?

Note that I can get this working in code, but it would be much more convenient to do this via the storyboard.

Comment: Found a possible "total conversion" tool that might be less painful programatically, but still no word on IB or storyboards.  It works something like this:  [[UITextView appearance] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"font name" size:18]];

Comment: Over a year later and still no word on this.  Let's hope that around WWDC time this gets addressed!

Answer (score 147, accepted):

### UPDATE: Xcode 6 Interface Builder now allows you to select custom fonts and will render them at design time correctly.

I know this question is quite old, but I've been struggling to find an easy way to specify a custom font in Storyboard (or Interface Builder) easily for iOS 5 and I found a quite convenient solution.

First, make sure that you've added the font to the project by following [this tutorial](http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app). Also remember that UINavigationBar, UITabBar and UISegmentedControl custom font can be specified by using the `setTitleTextAttributes:` method of the [UIAppearance proxy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiappearance).

Add the categories below to the project for UIButton, UITextField, UILabel and any other component that needs a custom font. The categories simply implement a new property `fontName` which changes the current font of the element while maintaining the font size.

To specify the font in Storyboard, just select the desired element (label, button, textview, etc) and add a *User Defined Runtime Attribute* with *Key Path* set to **fontName** of type *String* and value with the name of your custom font.

[image: Custom font Storyboard]

And that's it, you don't even need to import the categories. This way you don't need an outlet for every UI component that requires a custom font and you don't need to code it manually.

Take into account that the font won't show in Storyboard, but you will see it when running on your device or simulator.

---

### Category files

**UIButton+TCCustomFont.h**:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIButton (TCCustomFont)
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* fontName;
@end
```

**UIButton+TCCustomFont.m**:

```
#import "UIButton+TCCustomFont.h"

@implementation UIButton (TCCustomFont)

- (NSString *)fontName {
    return self.titleLabel.font.fontName;
}

- (void)setFontName:(NSString *)fontName {
    self.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:self.titleLabel.font.pointSize];
}

@end
```

**UILabel+TCCustomFont.h**:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UILabel (TCCustomFont)
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* fontName;
@end
```

**UILabel+TCCustomFont.m**:

```
#import "UILabel+TCCustomFont.h"

@implementation UILabel (TCCustomFont)

- (NSString *)fontName {
    return self.font.fontName;
}

- (void)setFontName:(NSString *)fontName {
    self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:self.font.pointSize];
}

@end
```

**UITextField+TCCustomFont.h**:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UITextField (TCCustomFont)
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* fontName;
@end
```

**UITextField+TCCustomFont.m**:

```
#import "UITextField+TCCustomFont.h"

@implementation UITextField (TCCustomFont)

- (NSString *)fontName {
    return self.font.fontName;
}

- (void)setFontName:(NSString *)fontName {
    self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:self.font.pointSize];
}

@end
```

Also downloadable [from GIST](https://gist.github.com/redent/7830234) and also as [a single file](https://gist.github.com/redent/7830234).

### Troubleshooting

If you run against runtime errors because the `fontName` property is not specified just add the flag `-all_load` under **Other linker Flags** in project settings to force the linker to include the categories.

Comment: Exactly the workaround I needed, thanks! In my case, I was bitten by the fact that UILabel doesn't support the appearance protocol(!)

Comment: This is an excellent answer and it's (almost) exactly what I was looking for.  Still, if you're developing for iOS 6 (in my case, Xcode 4.6.3) you will need to take one more step for your custom fonts to be displayed.  Hit your project in the navigator and go to TARGETS -> **Build Phases** and then hit the + button at the bottom of the **Copy Bundle Resources** panel.  Pick your custom font file and it should show up in the list.

Comment: That step is required for all iOS versions. By default, dragging the font to the XCode project will automatically add it as a resource. It was described in the tutorial link that I provided, but it seems that it's broken now. I've updated the tutorial link.

Comment: One thing to pay attention to since I kept missing it: once you create a new user defined runtime attribute, and type in the name for the keypath, if you don't press enter before selecting the string type, the keypath you just entered will reset. I kept wondering why I was getting a keypath error, and that's why.

Comment: Genius. I can't believe this bug (or lack of useful feature) still hasn't been added since iOS 3.2 when custom fonts appeared.

Comment: I found an implementation of this approach in CocoaPods as IPCustomFont.

Comment: I've tried to use a 'User Defined Runtime Attribute', and I've got the following error : "UILabel this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key fontName." Any idea of what I'm missing ?

Comment: @Tommecpe you are missing the last step, in the Troubleshooting section

Comment: thx, I brought the xCode Plugin MoarFonts (http://pitaya.ch/moarfonts/) and I'm very please with it.

Comment: I followed all the steps for custom fonts in storyboard  and I am using xcode 5.1 ...but I am getting runtime error.

Comment: @user1201239 you are probably missing the last step, in the Troubleshooting section

Comment: Juste a trick to help you : you can copy - paste the Runtime Attribute, just set it on the first Label or button, then stay in the panel, click on the other labels, and just paste the attribute to avoid wearing your fabulous keyboard...
@redent84 : Nice work, seems a good workaround to avoid managing an amazing number of unneeded outlets.

Answer (score 62):

From Xcode6.0 , as [Xcode6.0 release](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH4-SW2) note:

> Interface Builder renders embedded custom iOS fonts during design time, giving a more accurate preview of how the finished app will look, with correct dimensions.

you can set label font in storyboard.You can do as follow

1. Get you custom font file(*.ttf,*.ttc)
2. Import the font files to your Xcode project

   [image]
3. In the **app-info.plist**,add a key named **Fonts provided by application**.It's an array type , add all your font file name to the array,**note:including the file extension.**

[image]

4. In the storyboard , drag a UILabel to you interface,select the label , and navigate to the **Attribute Inspector**,click the right icon button of the **Font select area**.In the popup panel , choose **Font** to **Custom**, and choose the **Family** of you embeded font name.

[image]

## ref to

- [Xcode 6.0 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH4-SW2)
- [WWDC 2014 What's new in Interface Builder](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/)
- [IOS-Keys:UIAppFonts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html)

Comment: TCCustomFont not working in my xcode 6. So I use this method and its working.

Comment: it's worth to note, this method works perfectly with UILabels, but it's not working with UITextFields. I'm still trying to figure out how.. I guess realtime attributes would fix it

Comment: This only works when using plain UILabels, not ones with attributed text.

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug in XCode, been there since 3.x and still not fixed.  I too have faced the same issue, even tried adding it to my system with no luck.  Here is another SO post about it [Fonts not displaying in Interface Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398693/fonts-not-displaying-in-interface-builder)

Comment: I've looked around some and can't seem to find that this is a known issue by apple...  Do you know of a source for this?

Answer (score 3):

Monjer's answer is the correct one. If you, like me, don't see the added font after compiling, make sure to add the font's to the build phases (targets -> build phases -> copy bundle resources -> add your font files)

Answer (score 1):

As of XCode 9.4, XCode still does not respect fonts directly in the storyboard. You can see them at design time, but not at runtime. If you are using fontWithName API, you get to know it returns nil, but when used in storyboard/xib, there is no way to know why it doesn't appear.

- The only way to make sure it works readily from Storyboard/XIB at runtime is to add .ttc/.ttf into `Copy Bundle Resources` Build Phase.
- As of 9.4, adding font file names to info.plist seems no longer a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

redent84's solution was awesome!

I'd just add an improvement, add the category on NSObject, so you only have to do it once.

NSObject+CustomFont.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSObject (CustomFont)

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *fontName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIFont *font;

@end
```

NSObject+CustomFont.m

```
#import "NSObject+CustomFont.h"

@implementation NSObject (CustomFont)

@dynamic font;

- (NSString *)fontName
{
    return self.font.fontName;
}

- (void)setFontName:(NSString *)fontName
{
    self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:self.font.pointSize];
}

@end
```

Comment: Good idea. Sadly the `font` property of UIButton class has been deprecated since iOS 3.0, so it's not recommended for UIButtons.

Answer (score 0):

None of these worked for me, but this did.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UILabelEx : UILabel


@end

#import "UILabelEx.h"
#import "Constants.h"

@implementation UILabelEx

- (void) traitCollectionDidChange: (UITraitCollection *) previousTraitCollection {
    [super traitCollectionDidChange: previousTraitCollection];

    self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:APP_FONT size:self.font.pointSize];   
}
@end
```