# Show custom fonts in Interface Builder with UILabel's attributed string setting

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts, interface-builder

When I use the UILabel's attributed setting in Xcode 5's Interface Builder, it will show a preview on the storyboard for built-in fonts like American Typewriter. When I try to use it with a custom font, it only shows it in the preview area, not on the storyboard.

Is it possible to show the preview in the storyboard with custom fonts?

Here are some screen shot examples:

You can see that 'FOOBAR' shows the custom font in the inspector

[image: inspector]

But not on the storyboard

[image: storyboard]

Comment: Might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090745/custom-font-in-a-storyboard

Comment: Thanks for that link, @Msencenb, but it's not solving my problem.  If Im going to use storyboards, I want to be able to see what the layout will actually be, otherwise I might as well use code.  Strange there is no support for this!!

Comment: Its not even showing in the app when it is run.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 6 you need to select, highlight, the preview text in interface builder. Then change the fonts. You then will see it.

[image]