# Using custom font on Attributed UILabel

Tags: ios, fonts, attributes, uilabel

I try to set the Font of UILabel on Interface builder. I know how to user custom font by code. But I want to try cool feature on iOS 6 which is Attribute text type.

However, after testing a few font. I notice few things, I can set any font from `font book` and it is showed up really nice on `Attribute Inspector`. But some font are not showed up in View controller, event default font that already on mac is not loaded.

I want to use custom font on attributed `UILabel`, but it only showed up in `Attribute Inspector` and not loaded in View Controller and simulator.

[image]

Comment: What fonts are you using? http://iosfonts.com

Comment: Try setting `Lines` to `0`

Comment: first line is Bebas Neue, second line is Blackoak, and the last line is Chalkduster... I need to use custom fond aside from default ios font.

Comment: hope this ll help you.                            http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090745/custom-font-in-a-storyboard

Comment: That is only use 1 font for entire text.. I need to set different font on 1 UILabel... some of it gonna be bold, and the other is regular.. the bold and regular font is Bebas Neue, which is custom font.