# I can see my custom font in storyboard but the font is no change in iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios, fonts, storyboard

I use the way provided by @Monjer in [Custom font in a storyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090745/custom-font-in-a-storyboard)
I can see my custom font in storyboard but the font is no change in iOS Simulator.
Why this?

Comment: Which iOS version used in Simulator? Did you clean & rebuild? Any error shown?

Comment: Did you make this step? In the app’s pList file, add a new row and select the “Fonts provided by application” name for it.  This will create an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all @Raptor @Сергей Олейнич and @Ryan Forsyth.
I find my problem:
I don't tick the target when I drag my font to the project.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
NSArray *fontFamilies = [UIFont familyNames];
for (int i = 0; i < [fontFamilies count]; i++)
{
NSString *fontFamily = [fontFamilies objectAtIndex:i];
NSArray *fontNames = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:[fontFamilies objectAtIndex:i]];
NSLog (@"%@: %@", fontFamily, fontNames);
}
```

This will show all fonts in your application. search the returning result for your font you may find as is usually the cause the font name is actually different to the font family name.