# Custom Font not showing in Xamarin Storyboard

Tags: ios, fonts, storyboard, xamarin-studio

For my iOS project i need to use custom fonts. I added fonts in ***Resources/Fonts*** folder. And register the fonts in Info.plist [like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNkcl.png) In storyboard i am getting custom fonts [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwvlL.png) but the fonts not affecting in design. The **font style drop down** always empty see here "www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=1f07d04". I m working in *.storyboard* file not *.xib*

What have i done wrong?

Xamarin studio version - 5.10.3

Fonts used - Exo-SemiBold.ttf, Montserrat-Bold.ttf

Comment: why dont you apply it programatically

Comment: i am using more than 5 fonts, if storyboard handles the fonts it ll be more useful for me otherwise i need to set fonts for all elements by calling their name. more lines of code.

Comment: Just add constant file defining all those 5 fonts. It will be easy and you can change on one place.

Answer (score 5):

Ran into a similar problem. My custom fonts didn´t show up in Xcode at all.

Solution was to move fonts from **/Resources/Fonts/** up to **/Resources/** (And updating Info.plist accordingly). Doing so made them show up in Xcode.

Comment: I think this should be the correct answer. I tried and it is working fine. Thanks amu

Answer (score 0):

Try setting font programmatically.

After adding reference of your Font file in plist using "Fonts provided by application" key.

Then Log available fonts in AppDelegate method like this

```
NSArray *fontFamilies = [UIFont familyNames];

for (int i = 0; i < [fontFamilies count]; i++)
{
    NSString *fontFamily = [fontFamilies objectAtIndex:i];
    NSArray *fontNames = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:[fontFamilies objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSLog (@"%@: %@", fontFamily, fontNames);
}
```

In these logs you can find exact name of the font you want to apply.

Comment: Thanks Kiran. I ll try this. But is there any way to get fonts in storyboard itself? It ll be more useful.

Comment: See if this link helps you :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090745/custom-font-in-a-storyboard

Comment: I done all the steps from above link, but still i am not getting custom fonts in fonts list.