# Is there a way to add custom fonts to Xcode to be available from a storyboard?

Tags: xcode, uilabel, customization, uistoryboard, uifont

I know how to add custom font files to be shipped with an iOS app. I can then customize the label font from code using code like this :

```
UIFont* font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"League Gothic" size:42];
self.topLabel.font = font;
```

My concern is that such customization will "infect" all of the project and may require some significant rework later on. **Is there a way to include a font file into xCode itself, so it recognizes it and lets me select it from the storyboard font control?**

Comment: Alex, did you find a solution or you ended up applying font programmatically?

Comment: Check this link if helps : http://jayprakashdubey.blogspot.in/2014/08/using-custom-font-in-ios.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find the answer to this question over here

[Designing labels/text views with custom fonts in Interface Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683929/designing-labels-text-views-with-custom-fonts-in-interface-builder)

You can find a link regarding the same topic here

http://www.abdus.me/ios-programming-tips/set-custom-fonts-in-interface-builder/

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve it without having to relay on exposing `IBOutlet`s or adding external libraries is using categories and user defined runtime attributes from Storyboard or Interface Builder.

That way you can define your fonts in Storyboard or IB like this:

[image: Runtime Attributes]

You can get the code required for the categories from [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15155081/469218).