# Set the correct font to my app

Tags: ios, fonts

In my app I've to use custom font. The font I'm using is the [ProximaNova-Regular](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/marksimonson/proxima-nova/regular/). I'm trying to set it to the label in this way:

1. I imported the "ProximaNova-Semibold.oft" to my project
2. In the class in which I've to use I wrote this code:

`self.labelName.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ProximaNova-Semibold" size:10];`

I checked the full name of the font by checking directly from the Finder: I clicked with right on the "ProximaNova-Semibold.oft", then I clicked on "Full name" and in the window I copied the field "Complete name" to my project.
What's wrong? Why it doesn't use the font I'm trying to set by using the code I wrote above?

PS: I'm developing this app for iOS 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to YourApp-Info.plist and create a field "Fonts provided by application" "Array" and add :ProximaNova-Semibold.otf

Comment: I'm using iOS 7 when I go to the Info the file `applicationName.xcodeproj` I don't have a row in which there are written "Fonts provided by application", I've to create it?

Comment: Yes sir, "Fonts provided by application"

Comment: OK I will try now, just a sec

Comment: Glad to be of help :D

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer to this question over here

[Designing labels/text views with custom fonts in Interface Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683929/designing-labels-text-views-with-custom-fonts-in-interface-builder)

You can find a link regarding the same topic here

http://www.abdus.me/ios-programming-tips/set-custom-fonts-in-interface-builder/

Hope this helps you.