# Custom fonts in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, fonts, interface-builder

So we're in 2014, is there any way to set custom fonts within Interface Builder yet? Ie don't do it programmatically, except for "Fonts provided by application" in the app's plist.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683929/designing-labels-text-views-with-custom-fonts-in-interface-builder

Comment: May be the same question as follow: + [Designing labels/text views with custom fonts in Interface Builder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683929/designing-labels-text-views-with-custom-fonts-in-interface-builder/27339161#27339161)
+ [Custom font in a storyboard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090745/custom-font-in-a-storyboard/) May it be helpful.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Yes, Marrius is right. In Xcode 6, you neither need to use extra software nor to set Font in Code files. Just add your font files in your project along with other files. And Interface builder will display the added fonts in the Custom Font List.

And the most amazing thing is, xcode 6 shows the applied font instantly in IB. This is the great addition by Apple.

Also make sure to add this key "Fonts provided by application" in your project's info.plist and provide your font file names to see the effect in devices.

Comment: Yeah, but for some reason after adding the fonts to the project and setting the label's font in interface builder – the font doesn't show up on device. Looks just fine in IB though..

Comment: You're right. One thing more you should do. In your Project's Info.plist, you must add this key "Fonts provided by application". And provide your font file names. That would do work for the devices.This is the way the application would know that these fonts should be included in application's bundle.

Comment: But only if it's not an attributed string. At least not with FontAwesome nor Open Sans.

Comment: @FábioOliveira indeed, doesn't seem to work the attributed string.

Comment: Wow. What a "great addition" by Apple after more than 6 years of XCode being around for iOS... Sorry, I love XCode but this was just unnecessary torture for a long time. And the fact that it's still not working with Attributed Strings is just ridiculous.

Comment: But its really not reliable. I have added Open Sans font in my project and added the entries in info.plist file. Still the font is showing in custom fonts list for one xib but not for others.

Comment: @AsifBilal There was an additional step to make this work for me – had to manually add the attached font file(s) to the "Copy Bundle Resources" build phase, since XCode doesn't seem to do so automatically like with other files.

Answer (score 14):

In Xcode 6, we have custom fonts available in interface builder.

No need for extra software. Thank you Apple!

Comment: Yeah, but for some reason after adding the fonts to the project and setting the label's font in interface builder – the font doesn't show up on device. Looks just fine in IB though..

Comment: @NimaGardideh, isn't that the case for attributed text? I'm having the same.

Comment: I recall it not working for attributed text as well. Though, I think the problem fixed itself in one of the later betas.

Comment: But its really not reliable. I have added Open Sans font in my project and added the entries in info.plist file. Still the font is showing in custom fonts list for one xib but not for others.

Answer (score 9):

In Xcode 6, just add the ttf file in your project and use it in storyboard through custom fonts.
If you directly want to use it in your code without using it in storyboard then you have to add key "UIAppFonts" in projectName-Info.plist.

Example:

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key> 
<array>
    <string>Signika-Bold.ttf</string>
    <string>Signika-Regular.ttf</string>
    <string>Signika-Light.ttf</string>
    <string>Signika-Semibold.ttf</string>
</array>
```

just before the line `</dict>` in projectName-Info.plist.

```
UIFont* font  = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Signika-Regular" size:25];
```

Comment: its too hectic to attach each label with IBOutlet and then changing its font manually.

Comment: i spend so many times figuring out why I cant set font programatically. No I see the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like someone worked on it. You can have a look at [MoarFonts](http://pitaya.ch/moarfonts/) :

> MoarFonts
>
> Use custom fonts for your iOS projects directly in Interface Builder, the WYSIWYG way
>
> by Cédric Luthi “[0xced](https://twitter.com/0xced)”

It costs **10$**, but :

> Since iOS 3.2, you can use custom fonts in your iOS apps by adding the
>   UIAppFonts Info.plist key. Unfortunately, custom fonts are not
>   available when editing your xib files in Interface Builder. MoarFonts
>   makes your custom fonts available right within Interface Builder.
>
> MoarFonts is compatible with both Xcode 4 and Xcode 5.

Comment: Well, why not... I don't think I'll use it this time... but maybe this can give a hint to Apple to hire those guys ;-)

Comment: Or at least show them we need this functionality ! :D

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution, nothing else worked for me

```
#import "UILabelEx.h"
#import "Constants.h"

@implementation UILabelEx

//- (void)layoutSubviews
//{
//    [super layoutSubviews];
//    // Implement font logic depending on screen size
//    self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"CustomFont" size:self.font.pointSize];
//}

- (void) traitCollectionDidChange: (UITraitCollection *) previousTraitCollection {
    [super traitCollectionDidChange: previousTraitCollection];

    self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:APP_FONT size:self.font.pointSize];
}
@end
```

Comment: Crazy that this was the only thing that worked for me too. My custom fonts are accessible from code just fine. In interface builder, they appear in the font menus and are selectable. They are rendered correctly in interface builder. But when actually running in the simulator, it's Helvetica-city.

Comment: I think this is fixed in Xcode 8 but I haven't removed my code.