# Set a custom font without using attributed text

Tags: swift, xcode, fonts, custom-font

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but I'm trying to use `plain text` in a `UILabel` using storyboard to have a custom font. I can only see the fonts when I'm switching the text style from `Plain text` to `Attributed`.

**The steps I have done to install them:**

1. Dragged fonts into the project (`.ttf`)
2. Checked that the fonts are included as resources in my bundle
3. Include the fonts in my plist under `Fonts provided by application`-key

But the only way I can use my custom font is by setting the text to `attributed`. In my older projects, I have done the same procedure as above and been able to just change the font without having to put the `UILabels` to have attributed strings in storyboards.

Any clue on how I can manage this?

### Edit

When I'm using this following code below, I'm not seeing my custom font.

```
for family: String in UIFont.familyNames {
    print(family)
    for names: String in UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family) {
        print("== \(names)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the old one and drag your fonts again and check?

Comment: I tried it, but still the same. I started to wonder if it's a Xcode bug or something? @DharmeshKheni

Comment: Have you tried that on fresh project?

Comment: Yeah, just tried it out and still the same @DharmeshKheni

Comment: can you share demo project?

Comment: I tried to use another custom font and it worked without any problem. So I wonder what causes this with the other font. @DharmeshKheni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your demo project I have only add

```
lbl.font = UIFont(name:"Seravek",size:15)
```

in `viewWillAppear` and it's showing fine.

Comment: Is it possible to show the font in storyboard when setting font on a `UILabel`?

Comment: Its already answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398693/fonts-not-displaying-in-interface-builder And I am facing same issue

Comment: Funny fact. I set the custom font when the UILabel was using attributed text, and then I just switched back to plain text to keep the font. Hahaha...